# Comparing adamantane carbon types for accepting OH using MM ForceField

Tags: reaction-mechanism, energy, software

I want to compare two type of carbons accepting OH in adamantane which I've shown below.

[image: Atom positions]

I know the blue position is preferred. But I wanna prove it with energy optimization and MM Forcefield. I thought it is related to transition state and corresponding carbocations. But MM+ ignores all charges.

How can I test it using ForceField softwares ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try would be just to build the two isomers and compare their total energies .. that would at least show which position was preferred thermodynamically (i.e. more stable).  It sounds like you are more interested in the kinetic consideration though (i.e. which reacts faster) ... in that case, looking at the relative energies of the transition states will give you some basis for rationalizing the preference.  I am not sure how good MM is at dealing with transition states, however ... you would need to rely rather heavily on your chemical intuition to find the correct structures, and even then, the bond angles and bond lengths may be distorted to such an extent that your forcefield is not well parameterized to deal with them.